# How to connect Adobe Air client side with Java VM Debug Interface?

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, air, remote-debugging, jpda

I'd like to know if/how would it be possible to connect Adobe Air application to Java VM Debug Interface?  I have some objects residing on server side and don't want to change the code there and server already allows to do remote debugging.

Here's the information about JPDA:
http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/jpda/architecture.html

Greatly appreciate for your advice in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be very careful about opening the remote debugging interface to the Internet. That could be a huge security problem.

Security considerations aside, only a single debugger process can attach to the JVM at the same time.

You should really look at some of the more regular remoting protocols, such as SOAP or REST over HTTP(S) to talk to your server. This is not more work (probably less) than trying to shoe-horn JPDA into something it was not meant to do.